# Does Spread operator work differently in array and object?

Tags: javascript

I have tried implementing the below code.

The spread operator works with reference but it's working differently for an array, when I am trying to change any value of the old array using reference, it's not getting reflected in the new array but the same is working for objects.

```
const array=[12,40,63,21,22,32];
const copiedArray=[...array];
console.log(copy);    
arr[0]=92;
console.log(arr,copy); 
const p1=[{name:'Arabh' , age:39} ,{name:'Sana' , age:33}];
const p2=[...p1];
p1[0].name='Samir';
console.log(p1,p2);
```

Comment: It doesn't work differently, but there's a difference between *numbers* and objects, and a difference between changing the array (`arr[0] = 92]`) and changing an object in an array (`p1[0].name='Samir'`).

Comment: 1.  This is not reference.  If you want reference, use `copiedArray=array`.  
2.  You are not "working on object" - you are working on **array** (again/still) of objects.  
In either case, if you create a reference by using `copiedArray=array`, `array[any index]=number|object|whatever` will be seen in `copiedArray[any index]`.